# Create a new instance of component in Spring Boot/Framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot based application I’ve a @Component class that has code similar to this:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);

// Start a separate thread for each entry
Map<Long, Future<Integer>> calls = new HashMap<>();

for (MyClass info : list) {
    Callable<Integer> callable = new TableProcessor(info);
    Future<Integer> future = executorService.submit(callable);
    calls.put(info.getId(), future);
}
```

The AutoWiring is not working in the TableProcessor class because (I think) I am creating an instance using ‘new’.  What’s the best way to ‘create a new instance for each entry in my list’?

Note: Adding a ‘Bean’ to Application class won’t work in this case because I want a new instance for each thread.

Comment: And why wouldn't it work? Just add a bean make it prototype scoped and each time you need a fresh instance do a `getBean` on the `ApplicationContext` or `BeanFactory` instance.

Comment: M. Deinum - Sorry!  Bit newbie to this.  Sample code please. Otherwise I will google.  But your answer sounds promising.  Thanks.

Comment: Added this:
1)  Added 'applicationContext' object to this class.

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

2) Replaced 'new' with this:
Callable<Integer> callable = applicationContext.getBean(TableProcessor.class);

3)  In TableProcessor added this:

@Scope("prototype")

Seems to work!  Does this look good?

Comment: @DilTeam If it's working, all good, `@Scope("prototype")`  does the trick here creating a `new` bean for each time you do reference to it

Comment: BTW, I am using @ Controller for 'TableProcessor'.  What's the difference between @ Controller & @ Bean?  Actually, @ Bean shows error message in IDE (IntelliJ).

Comment: `@Bean` is to mark a method as a factory method for beans, `@Controller` is to mark a component to be a web controller. I would suggest replacing `@Controller` with `@Component` as your class obviously isn't a web controller.

Comment: Sorry! I meant to say difference between @ Bean & @ Component. I will leave it as a @ Component, but I am a bit confused.  @ Bean is to mark a "method"? I thought it's a class level annotation.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem and I solved it using the ApplicationContext.

Here's an example because I like to look at code rather than explain things, so maybe it will help someone in the same boat:

First, here's the Spring component that I want to create a new instance of:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class PopupWindow extends Window{

    private String someVar;

        @PostConstruct
        public void init(){
          //stuff
          someVar="hi";
    }
}
```

Here's the class where I want 2 instances of this Spring component:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class MainWindow extends Window{

    private PopupWindow popupWindow1;
    private PopupWindow popupWindow2;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        @PostConstruct
        public void init(){
          popupWindow1 = applicationContext.getBean(PopupWindow.class);
          popupWindow2 = applicationContext.getBean(PopupWindow.class);
    }
}
```

In my particular case, I'm using Vaadin + Spring, and these annotations use the Vaadin versions i.e. @SpringComponent and @UIScope instead of @Scope("session"). But the @Scope("prototype") is the same.